# disappearing glitch Parallax.js + Stellar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

I have been trying to find a solution to a problem for a while now on one of the projects Ive worked on.

It uses [parallax.js](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/) for making a ship look like its floating.
And on the foreground in the product bottle, but I wanted it to parallax so I used [Stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) for it. My skills in scripts are not that good so I could not customize either or to make them work on one type of code.

[The Site](http://bit.ly/xorum)

But there is a glitch in this, because each time someone goes to this site on google chrome it opens without the bottle, but if you refresh the page the bottle turns up.

On firefox, the bottle turns up on initial load but then disappears as you scroll.

I am failing to understand how to resolve this issue. Please, if someone who is experienced, can help me find out whats messing it, that would be great

```
<div id="parallaxscene">
<img src="images/pic.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
<ul id="scene">
<li class="layer" data-depth="0.40"><img src="images/ship.png" alt=""></li>
<li class="layer" data-depth="0" data-stellar-ratio="0.5"><img id="bottleparallax" src="images/bottle.png" alt=""></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqJMvr

Comment: The bottle on your live site shows up for me and doesn't disappear on both Chrome and FireFox. Also you CodePen is broken

Comment: thanks @zgood if you mean broken as in it doesn't show a preview that's cause the code is straight from the website. Thats strange this website has been up for months, and it does that to every one ive shown it to :(

Comment: The CodePen doesn't allow `<script>` tags in the javascript area... that's why it is throwing a fit. It did take the image a second to load (it is large) but both Chrome and FireFox displayed it for me

Comment: Agreed 300kb could be large, but it doesn't load for me till I refresh. Has not worked in my friends computer on different network too